How to inject a Cloudflare Turnstile token into Puppeteer?
I'm trying to automate access to a website that uses Cloudflare Turnstile. I've managed to get the token from cf-turnstile-response, but I don't know how to inject it to complete the challenge.
Context
With Google reCAPTCHA v2, I used to inject the token by accessing ___grecaptcha_cfg and running the callback. However, I can't find a similar way for Turnstile.
await page.waitForFunction(() => typeof ___grecaptcha_cfg !== 'undefined' && ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients);
const inyeccion_callback = await page.evaluate((recaptcha_token) => {
    const clients = ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients;
    for (const client of clients) {
        if (typeof client.callback === 'function') {
            client.callback(recaptcha_token);
        }
    }
}, recaptcha_token);

I haven't found how to access the Turnstile settings or run a similar callback. The token I get from resolution services (like 2Captcha) is already set as follows and I have manually confirmed that it is set:
document.querySelector('[name="cf-turnstile-response"]').value = 'TOKEN';
But once that is done I don't know how to call or verify that since the website in question doesn't have forms or buttons to validate, it just waits for it to be resolved to continue.
After injecting the Cloudflare Turnstile token into the cf-turnstile-response element I would like to know how to obtain and execute a callback to validate the entered token.

What's the website? Setting .value doesn't fire event handlers and seldom works, except for the most primitive form elements. I doubt Cloudflare would permit it.



const responseSelector = "#AreaCaptacha input[id*='cf-chl-widget']";        
await page.evaluate(
  (selector, value) => {            
    document.querySelector(selector).style.display = 'block'
    document.querySelector(selector).value = value;            
  },
  responseSelector,
  token
)



